# Remove everything after a specific special character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This Question is pretty much answered in this forum but for my situation which is exactly the same the answers I find here are not working.

I'm trying to remove all the characters after the pipe " | " in sql server. Any suggestions why it's not working?

query that i'm using:

```
SELECT left(name, charindex('|',name) -1) from table1
```

Error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

table1:

```
name
----
jack| rose|
wil |jo|rdy
karl||jay
jo smith
jjill
raj |kumar
```

Desired output:

```
name
----
jack
wil
karl
jo smith
jjill
raj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you're almost there - you just need to filter to ensure you aren't passing a negative number to the LEFT
e.g.,

```
SELECT left(name, charindex('|',name) -1) from table1
WHERE name LIKE '%|%'
```

Remember charindex is 0 if it doesn't exist in string, then you subtract 1. This means you're trying to do a LEFT(name, -1) which is invalid.

To get your full output (with all rows, regardless of the | symbol) you can use it in a CASE instead.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN [name] LIKE '%|%' THEN left(name, charindex('|',name) -1) 
        ELSE [name] END AS [name]
from table1
```

Edit: Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a53288aef63239ee9a35ed081ea3505) with results.

Comment: thank for the answer but what i'm seeing when i ran this query is that it is getting of 'jjill' in the final output, i guess it's only looking for those with PIPES and strings without PIPES are excluded

Comment: @Rob_irkland - Maybe you're running the first part only? See the second part for all rows and a db<>fiddle with results.

Comment: Also note - depending on use, you may also want to throw an RTRIM on the results to remove any remaining trailing spaces e.g., `WHEN [name] LIKE '%|%' THEN RTRIM(left(name, charindex('|',name) -1)) `

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select LEFT(name,CHARINDEX('|',name + '|')-1)
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT left(name, case when charindex('|',name)=0 then len(name)
else charindex('|',name)-1 end),charindex('|',name)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your query, its expecting values to have `|` always. So this will error on `name = jo smith'. Use` select case `to solve this.`

```
declare @str varchar(200)
set @str = 'jo smith'

select case when charindex('|',@str) > 0 then left(@str, charindex('|',@str) -1) else @str end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `LEFT`, use a combination of `STUFF` and `ISNULL`.

While `LEFT` will raise the "Invalid length parameter passed to the left function." error if it gets a negative length parameter,
`STUFF` will simply return null if it's starting position argument is less than less than 1.

This means that if the original value doesn't contain `|` and `charindex` return `0`, `stuff` will simply return `null`, and you can use `ISNULL` to return the original value in this case.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE  (
    [name] varchar(20)
);
    
INSERT INTO @T ([name]) VALUES
('jack| rose|'),
('wil |jo|rdy'),
('karl||jay'),
('jo smith'),
('jjill'),
('raj |kumar');
```

The query:

```
SELECT [name],
        ISNULL(STUFF([name], CHARINDEX('|', [name]), LEN([name]), ''), [name]) As Replaced
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
name            Replaced
jack| rose|     jack
wil |jo|rdy     wil 
karl||jay       karl
jo smith        jo smith
jjill           jjill
raj |kumar      raj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in a calculated field as:

```
(case when abs(charindex('-',[ColumnFormatted]))>(0) then substring([ColumnFormatted],(1),abs(charindex('-',[ColumnFormatted])-(1))) when abs(charindex(',',[ColumnFormatted]))>(0) then replace(substring([ColumnFormatted],(1),abs(charindex(',',[ColumnFormatted])-(1))),':','') else [ColumnFormatted] end)
```

Or as a SQL statement:

```sql
select (insert the above case statement here) as NewColummn
```